# Angular2 Binding not working on Observable

Tags: angular, observable

Calling a Rest service that receives credentials and retrieves a user.
     HTTP method is being executed fine, but the User object is not being updated and i can not bind it to the view:

**User Service (Connects to Rest Service):**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService
{
    constructor(private http:Http) {

    }

    public loginService(credential:Credentials):Observable<User>
    {

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

       return this.http.post
        ("http://localhost:8090/Users/"+credential.username, JSON.stringify(credential),options)
        .map((res) => res.json().user)
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    };
}
```

**View TS (holds the User object, credentials and calls the service):**

```
export class LoginComponent  {
credentials = new Credentials();
private user: User;

 private anyErrors: boolean;
 private finished: boolean;

 constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

login(){

this.userService.loginService(this.credentials).subscribe(
  function(response) {this.user = response ; console.log("Response from 
  service 1" + JSON.stringify(response))},
  function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
  function() { console.log("the subscription is completed")}
                  );
  console.log("Response from service 2" + JSON.stringify(this.user));
```

}

**HTML Template:**

```
   Username:  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="credentials.username" name="login"> <br>
   Password:  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="credentials.password" name="password" > <br>
   {{user.username}} // <--- THIS NOT BEING UPDATED WHEN CLICK login

<button (click)="login()">login</button>


---------------------------------------------
User Model:

export class User
{
    name:string;
    lastname:string;
    address2:string;
    email:string;
    phone:string;
    username:string;
    password:string;

    constructor()
    {

    }
}
```

**Credential Model**

```
export class Credentials
{
    username:string;
    password:string;

    constructor()
    {

    }
}
```

**Console**

Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
login.component.ts:33 Response from service 2{}
login.component.ts:29 Response from service 1{"name":"edgargdl","lastname":"flores","password":"password","email":"edgargdl@hotmail.com","phone":"2107847131","contactPreference":null,"username":"edgargdl","links":[]}
login.component.ts:31 the subscription is completed

Comment: can you try logging the response ?

Comment: You're using a function, not an arrow function, and not binding it correctly, so `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Yeah that was my issue, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very great fan of the Syntax you are using you can try this once.

```
  this.userService.loginService(this.credentials).subscribe(
  (response) => this.user = response,
  (error) => console.log("Error happened" + error),
  () => console.log("the subscription is completed"));
```

you are using the `function()` syntax the reference `this` is not accessible .Try using lambda's

Comment: any reason for the dv is appreciated? if not thanks for the dv man

Comment: Wow, i thought it was the same but different format, but seems there is a deeper meaning on the lambda expression on the scope.

Comment: Thanks a lot that fixed it !

Comment: @EdgarFlores the arrow functions preserves the value of `this` if not and you decide to go with functions you need to add`.bind(this)` at the end